# Mockk, How to mock JSONObject constructor which is used inside a private function

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

using mockk,  testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3"

having a class `MetaData` built through api `fun from(intent: Intent?): MetaData?`

```
class MetaData {

    @JvmField
    val rid: String
    ......

   private constructor(meta: JSONObject) {
        rid = meta.optString("RID", "")
    }

   companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun from(intent: Intent?): MetaData? {
            if (intent == null) {
                 return null
            }

            val metaJsonStr: String = intent.getStringExtra("meta") ?: return null
                   
            val rmeta = getMetaDataJson(metaJsonStr)
                ?: return null
                     
            return MetaData(meta)
        }
        
        private fun getMetaDataJson(json: String): JSONObject? {
            
            return try {
                JSONObject(json)
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                System.out.println("+++ !!! 111 exp in getMetaDataJson(), $e")
                null
            } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
                System.out.println("+++ !!! 222 exp in getMetaDataJson(), $e")
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

would like to test the code path which throws `JSONException` and `NullPointerException`.

Have tried this test the and it can test the null path from `intent.getStringExtra("meta")`

```
@Test
    fun test_from_WhenCalledWithIntentWithNometa_ShouldReturnNull() {
        val intentMock: Intent = mockk<Intent>(relaxed = true)
        every { intentMock.getStringExtra(any()) } returns null
        val metaData = MetaData.from(intentMock)
        Assert.assertEquals(metaData, null)
    }
```

How to make this test to step into the `getMetaDataJson(json)`, I guess that needs to not mocking the Intent but the JSONObject constructor (how)?

Or is it possible to stub the `fun getMetaDataJson(json: String)` but no matter what the input is it should replace the input `json` string to some configured test data?

How to test the two exception path?

Comment: This looks like something that should _never_ be mocked.  If you want to test the exception paths, then pass in strings that would cause the specified errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Creates a new {@code JSONObject} with name/value mappings from the JSON
 * string.
 *
 * @param json a JSON-encoded string containing an object.
 * @throws JSONException if the parse fails or doesn't yield a {@code
 *     JSONObject}.
 */
public JSONObject(@NonNull String json) throws JSONException {
    this(new JSONTokener(json));
}
```

The JSONObject construct will throw an exception if the passed string is not valid. Just pass a random string like `"This random: String"` and you should get the `JSONException`.

Regarding the `NullPointerException` you should not guard for this exception since the constructor doesn't throw it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Constructor mock](https://mockk.io/#constructor-mocks). It's available from `mockk 1.11.0`

Comment: not sure how would it help for the case that the object is instantiated inside a member function which is to be tested.